# Animate a value by scrolling position using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I want to animate a value (in my case `Dp` and `TextUnit` values) based on the scroll position in a `LazyColumn` scoped to the height of the LazyColumn. For those who can't imagine what I mean, [this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bFOG_KwPggqxZiGs3XTCOoOIqKtcjbuV/view?usp=sharing) describes exactly the animation I want to achieve.

- How can I achieve such an effect?
- What are best practices for that?

I look forward to your answers!

Comment: You can search for ```CollapsibleTopAppBar``` it can be achieved using it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [nested scroll](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/nestedscroll/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).nestedScroll(androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollConnection,androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollDispatcher)). You'll need a `NestedScrollConnection` attached to nested scroll system with `nestedScroll` modifier. Then you can react to scroll events emited by `LazyColumn` by overriding methods of `NestedScrollConnection`. There is an example at the link above and below is modified version that looks more like your video.

[image]

```
@Composable
fun ShrinkingHeader() {
    val density = LocalDensity.current

    val headerMinSize = 72.dp
    val headerMaxSize = 144.dp
    var headerSize by remember { mutableStateOf(headerMaxSize) }

    // Only need to find tabsHeight if it is not fixed
    var tabsSize by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize(0, 0)) }
    val tabsHeight by remember(tabsSize) { mutableStateOf(with(density) { tabsSize.height.toDp() }) }

    val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
        object : NestedScrollConnection {
            override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                fun deltaDp() = with(density) { available.y.toDp() }
                // Handle scroll up
                if (available.y < 0 && headerSize > headerMinSize) {
                    headerSize = max(headerMinSize, headerSize + deltaDp())
                }
                // Handle scroll down
                if (available.y > 0 && headerSize < headerMaxSize) {
                    headerSize = min(headerMaxSize, headerSize + deltaDp())
                }
                return Offset.Zero
            }
        }
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            // Attach to the nested scroll
            .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.zIndex(1f).background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface),
        ) {
            Header(headerSize)
            Tabs(modifier = Modifier.onSizeChanged { tabsSize = it })
        }
        LazyColumn(
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = headerSize + tabsHeight),
            // As header shrinks, we need to offset lazy column for consistent scrolling speed
            modifier = Modifier.offset(y = headerMaxSize - headerSize)
        ) {
            items(100) { index ->
                Text(text = "Item $index", modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp))
            }
        }
    }
}

// Shrinking header
@Composable
private fun Header(size: Dp) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(size),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    ) {
        Logo(size, Icons.Default.ArrowBack)
        Text("Middle")
        Logo(size, Icons.Default.ArrowForward)
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Logo(size: Dp, logo: ImageVector) {
    Icon(
        imageVector = logo,
        contentDescription = "logo",
        modifier = Modifier.size(size)
    )
}

// Composable on top of the list
@Composable
private fun Tabs(modifier: Modifier) {
    Column(modifier = modifier) {
        TabRow(selectedTabIndex = 0) {
            repeat(3) {
                Tab(selected = it == 0, onClick = {}, text = { Text("Tab $it") })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for yours anwer, it hasn't been exactly what I have been looking for but your answer helped me a lot!